# Odoo 13 Problems adding lot for products in mrp_production_templates.xml

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I need to add inside the manufacturing order pdf report the lot of the product that will be manufactured. The problem is that the field is always blank, like no value is being called for lot. No exception occurs. How do I make this value appears inside the report?

I created a new model inside the python file `mrp_production_with_lot.py` called `MrpProductionWithLots` to inherit `MrpProduction` model and add the `finished_product_lot` field:

```py
from odoo import fields, models, tools


class MrpProductionWithLots(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    finished_product_lot = fields.Many2one(
        'stock.production.lot', 'Lot/Serial Number',
        domain="[('product_id', '=', product_id), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]",
        check_company=True)
```

Then, I inherited the `mrp_production_templates.xml` and created a new python file called `mrp_production_with_lots.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_mrporder_inherit" inherit_id="report_mrporder">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='row mt32 mb32']" position="after">
            <div class="row mt32 mb32" id="finished_product_lot">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <strong>Finished product lot:</strong><br/>
                    <span t-field="o.finished_product_lot"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

I believe I'm not calling `finished_product_lot` right, but can't find the right way to call it.

Comment: How you set the field value? There a field named `lot_id` in the [finished_move_line_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/mrp/views/mrp_production_views.xml#L184). Do you need to show that field?

Comment: I think you wrong inherit id.Try use mrp.report_mrporder. Use module name in inherit id.mrp is example. Use your parent module name.

Comment: @Kenly yes, but I can’t do it

Comment: It work?Still problem?

Comment: what is the role of this field 'finished_product_lot' it is added manually?

Comment: @AungKoKoLin I am using the correct inheritance because I inherited a report that did the inheritance from `mrp.report_mrporder` and then expanded it.

Comment: @DipenShah yes, the role is to put inside the manufacturing order the associated with the product that will be produced.

Comment: @DipenShah the lot associated ***

Comment: @AndressaCabistani there is nothing "finished" on the original report, so i recommend to add a new "part" on that report right after the last table (loop on `move_raw_ids`). If there was produced something that will be in field `move_finished_ids`, so you should create a table on that field. Behind that field is model `stock.move` and you can loop on its field `order_finished_lot_ids` to get all "created" lots for a single move.

Comment: @CZoellner but I don't want the lots from the products that are being used as raw material, I want the lot for the product that will be produced with this raw material.

Comment: No you misunderstood me. You have to use `move_finished_ids` which are the produced goods. But i recommend to extend the original report right after the table of the used goods `move_raw_ids`. You could also replace the whole part of the used goods. Hint: The report is for producing employees, so it's probably better to create a complete new one? But i don't know your full requirements to give good recommdations :D